# In which layer do I access database in a MVC design

Tags: java, database, model-view-controller

I have a question regarding database access in a mvc application. Where should my database access logic placed?

should it be placed in each model? (if I have a Person model)

```
Person p = new Person();
p.save();
```

should it be placed in each controller?
or should I create a different set of classes only to perform the database logic, which means I have an additional layer in addition to model,view and controller?

How is this done? 
Also what if an ORM is used?

Comment: This question is too broad as it stands. What sort of application--is this a GUI or a Web application? How big is the data domain involved, and how complicated are your operations?

Comment: it's a web  application. assume it's a small web application

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In MVC pattern, M means models, V means view, C means controller. A common MVC application progress is that once a request is coming, controller get it and do necessary processing, retrieving results data, then pass the results data to view for rendering. After view layer is rendered, it displays to users via GUI.

Controller can be regarded as a commander, it controls process, but it is not good to handle data retrieving in controller. Model should be responsible for retrieving and organizing data. That means data objects should be stored in Model instead of Controller, Controller calls Model to retrieve data objects.

For your case, my suggestion is it needs following components:

1. `PersonController`, it calls `PersonService.savePerson(Person person)` method to save data(or in other case it retrieves result). I suggest Controller layer should be thin.
2. `PersonService`, it has method `savePerson(Person person)`, this method calls `PersonDAO.savePerson(Person person)` method to save/retrieve projects data(here it saves data), and maybe other handling. Here business logic goes.
3. `PersonDAO`, it has several methods which deal with `Person` objects(like `savePerson(Person person)`, `getAllPersons()`), deal with database in this layer. But these methods should be independent with business logic(as business logic should be deal in `PersonService`).
4. `Person` object, it is [value object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_object), it just defines what attributes a `Person` should have, like `name`, `age`, etc, with `get/set` methods, used for passing data through different layers. It does not deal with database at all.

While for uncomplex application, Service layer is not very necessary and can be integrated to Controller layer, which means just `PersonController` is ok.

Comment: it means i have Person.java PersonService.java and PrsonDAO.java. so there is a service layer and a DAO layer?

Comment: what is the difference between service layer and DAO layer?

Comment: @DesirePRG service/controller layer deals with business logic(such as login, first should check whether user exists, second check whether username/password aligned), DAO layer deals with database and does not contain business logic(DAO layer provides `isUserExists` and `checkNamePass` methods, but you see these 2 methods is not related to business logic).

Answer (score 2):

Others have pointed out that database access is a Controller function, but I recommend that you create a new library project to handle the database interaction. Typically this will have a name like "customerService.jar" - i.e. it encapsulates everythng you want to do to a customer. This will simplify your application, and add greatly to the reusability of your code.

This would be by approach:

- Define an interface that exposes business level operations (eg. **changeUserRole(long userId, Role newRole)** or **makePayment(long accountId, BigDecimal amount)** rather than the CRUD approach of **updateUser(User user)** etc. Typically some of the methods exposed by the interface will look like CRUD methods but might do more at the database end (e.g. check account status, maintain audit tables).
- Implement your business logic in this layer. Purists would say that there should be a separate layer for the business logic, but this makes it difficult to use SQL facilities (joins in particular) to efficiently access the database. In my experience these two layers need to be combined to keep the system simple and performant.
- Use an ORM tool to access the database and map from business objects to the database. (MyBatis is my favorite). If your database accurately reflects your business model, then you probably won't need separate DAO and business objects.
- Inject an instance of your customerService into your web MVC controller. The job of the controller is now to validate user input, populate the model, pass through requests to the customerService and put response data back into the model.

So if your needs change in future (e.g. You need to create an IOS or Android native app) you have a re-usable service that will happily do the job. Similarly if the architects insist on exposing it as a REST or SOAP service, you only need add the "glue logic" to implement the REST or SOAP service.

Also, it is easy to mock out the customerService in web unit tests.

Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

Its always better to segregate your code and group them according to their behavior. Model classes can be used as logical representation of your DB. You should have some Utility / helper classes which does your DB activities, and controller should interact with them.

Ideally you should have as many model classes (if not more) as you number of tables in the DB.

When you use ORM, the connections and mappings (once declared) are take care off by the framework and you focus on the business logic.

Comment: so i should have an additional layer for this database accessing?

Comment: Ideally you should segregate / group the classes based on the functions they perform, **if it means adding additional layers** please go ahead.

Answer (score 0):

In a Web application using a framework such as Spring or Jersey (which you should use), it's generally best to make your "controllers" (HTTP request handlers) as simple as is practical, wrappers around a service layer that contains your business logic such as database access. This both makes testing dramatically simpler, since you can test the business logic directly without the complication of HTTP requests, and makes it easier to reuse your business logic in future changes such as adding scheduled tasks.

When more than very simple CRUD operations are involved with something like a Person object, I will create a `PersonService` with methods that are expressed in terms of the business operations and inject that service into the controller. For simple CRUD operations, I generally use Spring Data repositories directly from the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Define function which accesses Db or which does DB related operations in your class file which we call it as Model and then access that function using that class object in Controller. Controller is just set of functions which give us DB results and assign those results to variables in Controller and access those variables in View which is your front-end